# Token type in the Authorization header is invalid,ebay api

Tags: rest, oauth, ebay-api

I am calling ebay api but this error occurs "Token type in the Authorization header is invalid". I have tried both application token and user token but this error is not resolving.How to solve this error.?

Answer (score 14):

You should change "Basic" with "Bearer".

```
Authorization: Bearer v^10#t^H5sI.... // your token
```

Api doc: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/rest-request-components.html#HTTP

Comment: Cannot upvote this enough. If you could include a link the relevant docs, that would improve this answer a lot.

Comment: Indeed you need to use `Bearer` in the Authorization header. Here is a link to the relevant documentation of the Ebay Request components documentation:  [HTTP headers for eBay REST requests](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/rest-request-components.html#HTTP)